# LAt Long to decimal Degree in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, latitude-longitude

I have data in a table which has Lat long as below.How can we convert them into decimal numbers like 43.360556 and -5.848889 using SQL query.Please advise.

```
   Latitude         Longitude
43-21-33.87-N   05-51-43.13-W
```

Comment: No, I reviewed it already ..not helpful for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Decimal Degrees = Degrees + minutes/60 + seconds/3600**

The math is pretty simple, so I would create a UDF, but you can use something like this

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table (ID int,Lat varchar(25),Lng varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'43-21-33.87-N','05-51-43.13-W')

Select A.*
      ,B.Lat
      ,C.Lng
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
               Select Lat=( xDim.value('/x[1]','float')
                           +xDim.value('/x[2]','float')/60.0
                           +xDim.value('/x[3]','float')/3600.0
                          )* IIF(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(25)') in ('N','E'),1,-1)
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.Lat,'-','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
 Cross Apply (
               Select Lng=( xDim.value('/x[1]','float')
                           +xDim.value('/x[2]','float')/60.0
                           +xDim.value('/x[3]','float')/3600.0
                          )* IIF(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(25)') in ('N','E'),1,-1)
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.Lng,'-','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Lat             Lng             DecLat      DecLng
1   43-21-33.87-N   05-51-43.13-W   43.3594166  -5.8619722
```

**EDIT Created a UDF (just for fun)**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Geo-DMS-Decimal] (@S varchar(max))
Returns Float
AS
Begin
    Return (
            Select ( xDim.value('/x[1]','float')
                    +xDim.value('/x[2]','float')/60.0
                    +xDim.value('/x[3]','float')/3600.0
                    )* IIF(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(25)') in ('N','E'),1,-1)
            From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@S,'-','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
            )
End
-- Syntax : Select [dbo].[udf-Geo-DMS-Decimal]('43-21-33.87-N')
-- Syntax : Select [dbo].[udf-Geo-DMS-Decimal]('05-51-43.13-W')
```

Comment: Awesome.. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user1046415 Happy it helped